# Symfony ORM Annotation in Trait doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, traits

When I use a Trait inside a class the fields and methods are added but part of the ORM Annotation are lost.
*Example:*
**FILE: CommonFields.php**

```
Trait Commonfields
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="test", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private test;

    public function getTest()
    {
         return $this->test;
    }

    public function setTest($test)
    {
        $this->test = $test;
    }
}
```

**FILE: My.php**

```
class My
{
    use CommonFields;
    // ...the rest of My class 

}
```

When I sync the Entity with the database: **php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force**
I lose that "nullable" and "length" options, that are specified in the @ORM Annotation.
If I define the same field and related annotation in the Class My, it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but I had the same problem and I fixed it by clearing the cache and then `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`

Hope that someone find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

you should probably use a mapped superclass when dealing with entities.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html

Comment: thanks but that's not what i'm looking for. I started from here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21656028/how-to-add-extra-fields-and-related-getters-setters-from-an-external-file-to-one
I need a solution without inheritance.